# How to preserve dataset order when using DDP in pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I need to be able to preserve the order in which the data is fed to the model when training in multiple GPUS.
According to https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/discussions/13342 each GPU gets a consecutive fraction of the dataset, so if I have 2GPUs, the first one will get the first half of the dataset and the other one will get the second half of the dataset.
I need to preserve the order and don't know how to overwrite the dataset-splitting logic. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer here
https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/discussions/15164
which is to basically write a custom DistributedSampler and pass it to the dataloader and set Trainer(replace_sampler_ddp=False)

My code is something like this

```
 def train_dataloader(self):
    """returns a dataloader for training according to hparams

    Returns:
        DataLoader: DataLoader ready to deliver samples for training
    """
    # define a distributed sampler in case we are using multiple GPUs
    if self.hparams.num_gpus>1:
        sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
            self.train_dataset, shuffle=False)
    # only use the sampler if using multiple GPUs
    return DataLoader(
        self.train_dataset,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=self.hparams.num_workers,
        batch_size=self.hparams.batch_size,
        pin_memory=False,
        sampler=sampler if self.hparams.num_gpus > 1 else None)
```